# Not a HASH reference in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to fix some old code that is not working anymore with a Perl new version. Unfortunately, I have never coded in Perl yet.

This line is currently causing an issue. I have a compilation error.

```
my @IDs = values($Body->{'ConfigItemSearchResponse'}->{'ConfigItemIDs'});
```

> Experimental values on scalar is now forbidden at
> ./CMDBcertificateCheck.pl line 266. Type of arg 1 to values must be
> hash or array (not hash element) at ./CMDBcertificateCheck.pl line
> 266, near "})"

I tried to fix it by dereferencing the $Body but now it's not accepted to initialize my array @IDs.

```
my @IDs = values(%{$Body->{'ConfigItemSearchResponse'}->{'ConfigItemIDs'}});
```

> Not a HASH reference

Here is the content of the $Body if I dump it.

```
print Dumper($Body->{'ConfigItemSearchResponse'}->{'ConfigItemIDs'});
```

> $VAR1 = [
> '646',
> '650',
> '2178',
> '2179'
> ];

Could you help me to put the content of the `$Body` variable inside the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dereference the array with `@{}`.  I see no need to use [values](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values) here:

```
my @IDs = @{ $Body->{'ConfigItemSearchResponse'}->{'ConfigItemIDs'} };
```

Comment: For Perl >= 5.24, you can use postfix dereferencing: `my @IDs = $Body->{'ConfigItemSearchResponse'}->{'ConfigItemIDs'}->@*;`